# Run github action when pushing to a certain branch

Tags: github-actions

I want to run an action to check if my code compiles whenever I push to dev branch. But since my actions are in main it never runs whenever I push to dev branch. I have tried to understand the documentation but it really isn't any help. Here is the code:

```
name: check-compile
on:
  push:
    branches: 
    - dev
```

Comment: I just made a test here, it will work adding `'` around the name branch, to match against refs/heads, so using `'dev'` will do it: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/15-push-dev.yml

Comment: Yeah I already tried that doesn't work for me, is it possible this doesnt work because my workflows are in my main branch and not my dev branch?

Comment: I tested here and it only ran when the workflow was on the specific branch (here `dev`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways to run workflow for specific branches.

**First option**

The one you wrote only work if `dev` is the default branch, to make it work with other ref/heads you need to add `'` around the branch name:

```
name: check-compile
on:
  push:
    branches: 
     - 'dev'
```

[More information here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-branches-and-tags)

*Note: It will only work with this implementation if the workflow `.yml` file exists on the specific branch.*

**Second option**

You can run your workflow for all push, but perform specific jobs of steps only for specific branches. To do so, you can use the `if` conditional on the `job` or the `step` level:

```
name: check-compile
on: [push] #to any branch
jobs:
  job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev' # run this job only for the dev branch
    steps:
      ...
```

[More information here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#)

**Third option**

You can also filter branches using `!`, to run the workflow on any branch except the ones informed:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
      - '!master'
```